# Insert and delete in database with ajax in while loop

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am trying to insert and delete from database with ajax in a while loop. I have rows coming from database in while loop and in these rows last column is select or cancel. I have done till select option. When i click on select it insert value in to database and on same time i want to hide select button of that row only and display the cancel button and on click cancel i want to delete that row from database and then again want to display select button that row. following is the code which i have done till now. Please check. Need help. Thanks in advance..

Code :

Following rows are fetched from mysql in while loop :

```
<tr>
    <td>$crs</td>
    <td>$clg</td>
    <td>
        <form name="form_submit_change_status" class="form_submit_change_status" action="">
            <input type="hidden" name="crs" class="user_id" value="<?php echo $crs; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="clg" class="clg" value="<?php echo $clg; ?>">
            <button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs is_enabled" value="Select">Select</button>     
        </form>

        <div class="delete_change_status" style="display:none;">  
            <button>Cancel</button>   
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Javascript code :

Hide and show buttons and insert in to database code :

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('.btn.btn-warning').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $form = $(this).closest(".form_submit_change_status");
        var formData =  $form.serializeArray();
        var userId =  $form.find(".user_id").val();

        $(this).hide(".is_enabled");
        $(this).show(".delete_change_status");


        var URL = "response.php";
        $.post(URL, formData)
        .done(function(data) {


        });

        fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //failure    
        });

        var $isStatus = $form.find(".is_enabled");
        var varChangeStatus = $isStatus.val();

    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: I think you should use `serialize()` instead of `serializeArray()` for posting data.

Comment: and what's the exact problem ?

Comment: insert in to database is working fine.. but i want to hide select button and show cancel button on click select button and then again on click cancel button again want to show select button. and delete that row in database

Comment: will i get any help for my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

How about with such corrections?

From

```
$(this).show(".delete_change_status");
```

to

```
$(".delete_change_status").show();
```

"this" in chrome means "button.btn.btn-warning.btn-xs.is_enabled".
If you click on select button , you will see from "select" to "cancel".

```
$(function(){
    $('.btn.btn-warning').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $form = $(this).closest(".form_submit_change_status");
        var formData =  $form.serializeArray();
        var userId =  $form.find(".user_id").val();

        $(this).hide(".is_enabled");
        $(".delete_change_status").show();


        var URL = "response.php";
        $.post(URL, formData)
        .done(function(data) {

        })
        .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //failure
        });


        var $isStatus = $form.find(".is_enabled");
        var varChangeStatus = $isStatus.val();

        console.log(varChangeStatus);

    });
});
```

Comment: Its not working. Onclick it refrsh the page without any change

Comment: @Shadow,  Can you plz give any solution?

Comment: After removing $(this) it display cancel button in all rows which have class delete_change_status